# Using nodejs app as Windows Service causes EPERM-4048 ERROR

Tags: node.js, windows, service, node-modules

I'm using "[node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows)" for creating service that will run my app.js server
on windows.
This is the code that makes the service (using node-windows module)-

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object 
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Demo Landing Page',
  description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
  script: 'app.js'
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the 
// process is available as a service. 
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

All works fine with the script but this line for reading directory content-

```
fs.readdir([PATH], function(err, builds)
```

This is the error that I get -

```
{Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir [PATH]
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'app.js' }
```

But If I run not as a service - just as-

```
node app.js
```

all works fine, permissions are fine.

What can I do in order to fix this?
Or maybe there is another option for running nodejs on windows server?

Thanks!

** I sign in as administrator and I have access to the following dir

Comment: when your run it as a service, which account is used ? yours ? maybe system's ? does it has access to your dir ?

Comment: administrator account, it has access.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on service
open its properties
check what account its using under logOn

[image]

Either try this in service above code

```
svc.logOnAs.domain = 'mydomain.local';
svc.logOnAs.account = 'username';
svc.logOnAs.password = 'password';
```

or you can directly add credentials and restart the service